# SXA theme show in Experience Editor, but not on published site unless I publish the whole site

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, publishing

I can edit and view my custom SXA theme in the Experience editor with the Creative Exchange Live, but the theme doesn't appear on the website unless I publish the whole site.

I tried to publish the theme, the themes folder, the media library, but nothing work unless I publish the whole site and I would like to avoid this, since there could be a lot of content aka this could end taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to publish the Site Theme through XA tab on the Experience Editor using Publish > Site Theme.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't update the theme unless I do a publish site :(

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the log?

Answer (score 2):

**Deploy if not Publishing**

In order to evaluate the problem, You can go to the specific file in your theme and deploy it. This way, you will see that the file is published `( deploy is same as publish for theme files )`

[image]

**Theme Settings**

Also make sure, you have set your desired theme in your Theme Settings.
[image]